# Email of specific data rang / table from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

```
function B2B() {

  var summary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
  var subject = "B2B - Delivery Status on";
  var recipient = "******@***.in";
  var dataRange = summary.getRange('B2:AA49'); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  summary.getRange(2, 2, 25, 25).getValue;
  var body = "I just discovered Apps Script and it's so cool!" + data;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

}
```

Used this query which is working and mail is going but, selected data range is table which i am not getting in table format in the mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function B2B() {

  var summary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
  var subject = "B2B - Delivery Status on";
  var recipient = "******@***.in";
  var dataRange = summary.getRange('B1:AA49');
  var [headers, ...rows] = dataRange.getValues();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: "I just discovered Apps Script and it's so cool!" + "<br><br>" + tableHTML([headers], rows)
  })

}

function tableHTML(headers, data) {
  var tableformat = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc"';
  var header = headers.map(h => '<tr><th>' + h.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>')
  var rows = data.map(r => '<tr><td>' + r.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>')
  return '<table ' + tableformat + ' >\n' + header.join('\n') + rows.join('\n') + '</table>'
}
```

you need htmlbody instead of body

tableHTML is a function that will tranform the data into a table

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)